# Firebug extension: get info from Net Panel

Tags: javascript, firebug

I'm creating a very simple Firebug extension to capture page load data. I have recently found out that I can access the information in the net panel in my extension, but I have not seen any examples of how to read data from the net panel directly.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

**Note:** This is not about using a net listener. This is about literally reading the contents of the last row of the net panel. Also, other extensions do not fulfill my requirements, so please do not suggest them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var panel = FirebugContext.getPanel("net");
var summaryRow = panel.table.querySelector(".netSummaryRow");
```

This is how you can access the summary row in the Net Panel. More magic needs to be done to get data, but this answers my question!